Have a problem to get median in DAX power bi, can anyone please have a look?
The following code gives the total sum, not the median
Median CW = 

var StartDate =  MAX('Date'[dt])

var Result = CALCULATE(
        CALCULATE( MEDIANX( 'ogd', 
                            SUMX(GROUPBY('ogd', 'ogd'[fam], 'ogd'[amt]), 'ogd'[amt])),
                    FILTER('ogd', ('ogd'[dt1] > StartDate || ISBLANK('ogd'[dt2]))
                    && 'ogd'[dt0]<=StartDate 
                    && 'ogd'[end] > StartDate)),
        REMOVEFILTERS('Date'),        
        USERELATIONSHIP('Date'[dt], 'Date Compare'[dt])
    )     
return
   Result

can anyone please have a look at it and any suggestions are highly appreciate it.

Can you provide data instead of images ?
